# Why does the shadow of my finger appear blue? Is it due to Rayleigh scattering?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, shadow

The shadow of my finger appears blue on a page of the book which is facing away from the source of light. Is this due to the scattering of light?

Comment: You should specify the observation conditions better. If it's indoors, and the shadow being lighter than black is not due to the light from the window, then Rayleigh scattering can't be the reason because there's too small volume for noticeable scattering of the light from the lamp.

Comment: It happened during the morning. The light source was the sunlight coming through my window

Comment: The colour also changes when I switch on the led white light to light orange. Is there any particular phenomenon behind this?

Comment: By volume, do you mean volume of sub wavelength particles?

Comment: By volume I mean that, yes. In the room you have too low amount of molecules to significantly Rayleigh-scatter the light from you lamp. Were you close to the window? If yes, then indeed, as the answer you got says, the blue must be from the sky. If you're far from the window (was it sunrise?), the shadow might be lit more by the light from the walls. In this case, if the walls aren't blue, the blueness you see might be related to chromatic adaptation of your vision, where the orange/yellow light from the Sun would be perceived as more white than it actually is (and its lack would seem bluer).

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: Can dust particles significantly Rayleigh scatter light?

Comment: Dust particles Mie-scatter light. This usually results in the color that's the same as the source of light, without bluing (similarly to fog particles).

Comment: I cannot observe this blue colour of my shadow anymore.  Is there any particular reason to this?

Comment: Is it maybe due to the differing wavelength of the light source?

Comment: I also wear glasses so is it related to that maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Shadows often appear to have a slight blue tint because of scattering of light in the atmosphere. This is the same reason why the sky appears blue. Your finger blocks most of the light travelling towards the region of the shadow, but it cannot block that light that is scattered by air from other directions.

Comment: Does my finger then reflect the light which ultimately  gets scattered ?

Comment: The scattered blue light is only significant in the region of the shadow, since there aren't any other light sources targeting that region. Your hand may reflect this blue light but that isn't the significant factor here.

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: Imagine an ant sitting in the shadow of our finger looks around. What does it see? Some dark cylindrical object in one direction, but bright blue sky in most other directions. So it sees a lot of blue light. Accordingly, it is blue light that reaches the paper and gets (diffusely) reflected

Comment: I see,  thank you